# Is there a way to customize the diff algorithm used by GitHub's compare view?

Tags: github, diff, githooks, github-enterprise

I would like to try replacing GitHub's diff algorithm (which I read somewhere is some variant of PatienceDiff, but—whatever it is) with other experimental / heuristical algorithms. But, specifically in the Compare view. Critically, I want to preserve the style and especially the ability to comment on lines, permalink to lines, etc.

How can I achieve this, if at all, for example using something like GitHub's services or hooks, or some other integration API? Is it even possible?

I'm looking for either a solution or a clear reason this couldn't possibly work. (I'm tending toward the latter because it seems GitHub preprocesses its diffs server-side, returning a purely HTML/CSS result in asynchronously loaded chunks. But, maybe someone cleverer than I might know or see a way.)